# Performing bitwise not on a byte

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I am attempting to perform a bitwise not on a byte, like this:

```
byte b = 125;
byte notb = ~b; // Error here
```

This doesn't work because the not operator only works with integer types. I can do this, and this seems to work:

```
byte b = 125;
byte notb = (byte)((~b) & 255);
```

This seems to work because its not'ing the number, then flipping all bits after the 8th bit to 0, then casting it to a byte. What I am wondering is if there is a better way to do this or a simpler way that I am just overlooking?

Comment: Your resolution is about as good as it gets.  C# doesn't seem to fully support bit operations on types other than `int` as the result is always forced to an `int` making it is up to you, the programmer, to fix Microsoft's oversight by masking the result and casting it back to the type you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like Lynx is planning on updating his answer, so for future reference, bitwise operators work fine on `byte`. They just return an int, which is not assignable to a variable of type `byte`. You only need one cast here:

```
byte notb = (byte)~b;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically better than the one that you wrote because it is more clear. I have read some topics about this thing, but it seems like you can't really use a bitwise not on a byte.

```
byte b = 125;
byte notb= (byte)~b; // result is 130
```

Comment: You cann use a bitwise not. The byte-type is unsinged, which means its range is from 0 to 255. As you can see in your calculator 
125 => 0b_0111_1101; and the negotiation is
byte byte_not125 = 0b_1000_0010; // 130

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
byte b = 125;
byte notb = (byte)~(int)b;
```

This is casting b to `int` and then doing `~` and casting it back to `byte`.

I've verified result. Both your and my code outputs `130`.